# How do I create a column that tells me the the count of how many times a number appears?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import ast

s = requests.Session()

page=1
traits = []

#Get URL and extract content
class Scraper():

    while page != 10:
        content = s.get('https://bullsontheblock.com/api/tokens/{}'.format(page))
        soup = BeautifulSoup(content.text, 'html.parser')
        page = page + 1
    
        traits = ast.literal_eval(soup.text)['attributes']

        df = pd.DataFrame(traits).set_index('value').to_numpy()
        trait_count = len(df)
    
        print(trait_count)
```

Whenever I use the above code I get integers separated by line like this:

```
9
8
8
8
6
9
8
8
7
```

How do I create a column that tells me the the count of how many times a number appears so it looks something like this instead:

```
9 - 2
8 - 5
7 - 1
6 - 1
```

Basically the code above pulls the count of how many traits are in a list, but I have multiple lists so I would like to pull the count of how many times a list with a certain number of traits appear so it can look like the above. How do I go about this?

Comment: Given a value, do you know how to append it to a list? Given a bunch of values, one at a time, can you think of a way to use appending to create the list you want? (what should the list look like before you start appending?) Did you try to write code following this idea? What happened when you tried that?

Comment: "How do I create a column that tells me the the count of how many times a number appears so it looks something like this instead" That isn't "a list of numbers". You should title your question according to what you're actually asking.

Comment: That said: are you familiar with the word `histogram`? (If not, look it up in a dictionary.) Do you see how that relates to the question you're asking? Does this help you to use a search engine to find a solution?

Comment: @intermarketics i think the data structure you're looking for is a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries). This serves you much better than a list checking how frequently a value appears.

Also, please show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments and @PyxlDavon's answer, you likely want to use a dictionary:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import ast

s = requests.Session()

page=1
traits = []
traits_d = {}

#Get URL and extract content
class Scraper():
    
    while page != 10:
        content = s.get('https://bullsontheblock.com/api/tokens/{}'.format(page))
        soup = BeautifulSoup(content.text, 'html.parser')
        page = page + 1

        traits = ast.literal_eval(soup.text)['attributes']

        df = pd.DataFrame(traits).set_index('value').to_numpy()
        trait_count = len(df)

        if trait_count in traits_d:
            traits_d[trait_count] += 1
        else:
            traits_d[trait_count] = 1
```

traits_d contains the trait and number of times seen:

```
traits_d
{9: 2, 8: 5, 6: 1, 7: 1}
```

To print the keys out as you show, loop through the sorted keys:

```
       
for key in sorted(traits_d.keys(), reverse=True):
    print(key, '-', traits_d[key])

9 - 2
8 - 5
7 - 1
6 - 1
```

Comment: This answer worked, thank you. I have one more question though, how would I go about adding this to a column in a dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

Add each numbers to a string, then count the frequency of each number

```py
nums = "988869887"
fre = {}

for num in nums:
    if num in fre:
        fre[int(num)] += 1
    else:
        fre[int(num)] = 1

print(fre)
```

Output
`{9: 2, 8: 5, 6: 1, 7: 1}`

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else ever has the same problem I'm having: @garlic_rat's answer was spot on but I was still having trouble with trying to get it into a dataframe but I solved my problem by using the following code:

```
# Import libraries
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import time
import ast

start_time = time.time()
s = requests.Session()


#Get URL and extract content
page=1
traits = []
traits_e = []

while page != 10:
    content = s.get('https://bullsontheblock.com/api/tokens/{}'.format(page))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content.text, 'html.parser')
    page = page + 1
    
    traits = ast.literal_eval(soup.text)['attributes']

    df = pd.DataFrame(traits).set_index('value').to_numpy()
    trait_count = len(df)
    traits_e.append(trait_count)
    
a = pd.DataFrame({'Trait Count': traits_e})
value_counts1 = a['Trait Count'].value_counts()
l1 = [f"{key} - {value_counts1[key]}" for key in value_counts1.keys()]
traits = l1

dfx = pd.DataFrame(
    traits, columns=['Trait Count'])

print(dfx)
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

By doing this I was able to receive the same data as @garlic_rat's answer but this also allowed me to put it into a dataframe column.